# "your account is restricted or locked. Go to www.paypal.com to resolve this issue." this error is shown when try to make high-value payments

Tags: android, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am making an e-commerce app for android. And i have used MPL for make parallel payment.

When i tried to make payment greater then $3000 by android device using MPL then it does not able to login. It show an error(**your account is restricted or locked. Go to www.paypal.com to resolve this issue**).

But When i have tried to make payment by same paypal account and total amount is greater then 3000 by Web. Then it has successfully login without any error. 
But paypal need some additional information(like Social Security Number, Passport Number, Alien Registration Number etc) for make complete payment on web.

So I want to know, Is any method there on my side(MPL android) to perform high value payment.

Thank You

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question which should be asked of the Customer Service department for the company you are dealing with. Please see: [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746) and [Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/).

Answer (score 1):

As far as my communication went with PayPal support - there is no way to pass the restrictions, other than getting you account fully verified. PayPayl need additional information, so they can prevent financial frauds. You are supposed to provide this info, in order to lift all your limits.

I provide you with information from PayPal support - I understand, that you might not be in the EU, but the difference is only on the amount. The logic is the same:

> Thank you for contacting PayPal regarding  'receiving limit'. I have
>   reviewed your account and it show taht your account is fully active
>   and you can send and recieved money. European Union
>   anti-money-laundering and ‘Know Your Customer’ regulations require
>   that we collect and verify certain information from you. Until this
>   verification process is complete, you’ll have a receiving limit on
>   your account. This means that you can receive a maximum of €2,500 EUR
>   into your PayPal account in total cleared payments each year. Your
>   receiving limit goes into effect when you receive your first payment
>   and is reset every year after that on the same date. When you provide
>   the requested documents, we will review them and during that time you
>   can use all features of your account. If the review of your account is
>   not completed after you have received €2,500 EUR into your PayPal
>   account, some features of your account will become limited. We will
>   then prioritise your review and complete the process within a few
>   days. Here’s how to remove the receiving limit on your account: Go to
>   www.paypal.com and log in to your account. At the bottom of the page,
>   click See how much you can send with PayPal. Check the steps required
>   to remove your limits and follow the instructions. If you don’t have a
>   Business account but you sell items on eBay or on your own website,
>   select ‘Individual’ from the ‘Business Type’ menu and then complete
>   those sections that apply to you. I believe this information was
>   helpful and I have answered to your question. Thank you for choosing
>   PayPal. We are always here for you. Yours sincerely,  PayPal

Comment: Thanks @Kris for your effort. And I will follow the steps they have suggested.